# T-SQL to text: set column width as required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got a piece of sql script which I run with the output set to text.
The column it returns is set to `varchar(255)`, so in the text output the column is 255 chars wide.

I know I can use

```
Cast(ColumnName As VarChar(75))) As ColumnName
```

to restrict it down to 75 characters width, but what I want to achieve is that it automatically sets the width to the widest result it returns. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Do you mean setting width of a UI element? You can set it to `Max(Len(ColumnName))` .

Comment: What do you mean by "text output"? `VARCHAR(X)` is for text of varying length up to X characters, so the value you get will be exactly the length of the content, as oppsed to `CHAR(X)`, where every value will be *exactly* X characters long, filled with spaces if shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic query to achieve the result.

See one sample script below.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(Column1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #temp (Column1) VALUES ('1111-123'),('15454454aa-4545')

DECLARE @Delimit INT
DECLARE @queryString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Delimit=MAX(LEN(Column1)) FROM #temp --Getting the Length of largest column data

SET @queryString='SELECT CAST(Column1 AS VARCHAR('+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@Delimit)+'))Column1 
                  FROM #temp'
EXEC(@queryString)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, only used dynamic SQL once before, but understand your solution, thanks